# Angular filters

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I have the following code:

```
<select name="condition"
    ng-options="operation.id  as operation.description for operation in Operators  | myfilter:criterion_id" > 
</select>
```

and

```
module.filter('myfilter', function () {
  return function (x) {
    return  ?????
  };
});
```

I want to populate my select list with those options whose `operation.id` **equals** `criterion_id`. How may I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should filter your array based on a condition and return the filtered array.

```
module.filter('myfilter', function () {
  return function (arrayOptions, criterion_id) {
    var result = [];
    result = arrayOptions.filter(function(operation){
        return (operation.id == criterion_id);
    })
    return result;
  };
});
```

But you should do this in case of a complex filtering process with data manipulation, otherwise you should use filter `filter`  from Angular.

```
Operators  | filter: {id: criterion_id}
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to make your own filter, Angular's default `filter` will work:

```
<select name="condition"
    ng-options="operation.id  as operation.description for operation in Operators | filter:{id:criterion_id}" > 
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just written some code here.. please check it:
http://jsfiddle.net/k86sy0ku/1/

```
    <select 
        ng-options="p as p.first for p in people |  filter:{id:FilterId}"
        ng-model="selectedPerson"></select>
```